# C4003 not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'CreateWindowW'

Tags: c#, c, windows, visual-c++, game-development

I am new and am following some guy on youtube, I fixed most of the problem but am stuck with this error while creating my window tab. its in this line :

```
CreateWindow (window_class.lpszClassName, "Weeeee!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280 * 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0 );
```

and some of the error in the same line are "expected an expression" , "syntax error: ')'"

the entire code for reference:

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX
# define NOMINMAX
#endif
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = L"Game Window Class"; 
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback; 

    RegisterClass(&window_class);

    CreateWindow (window_class.lpszClassName, "Himesh Xakko", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280 * 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0 );
}
```

I pasted some lines of code from this page like

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX
# define NOMINMAX
#endif
```

did not fix anything

Comment: HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, L"Himesh Xakko", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

Comment: What is `1280 * 720` meant to be? Did you count the parameters you're passing to the macro?

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww).

Comment: the 720 is supposed to be the res of the window that would pop up

Comment: fixed it seems that 'L' fixed it all, Thanks!!!

Comment: @Monofen No, adding `L` didn't fix it all. You had the wrong number of parameters before.

Comment: "the 720 is supposed to be the res" What do you mean by "the res"? This is just a single number. Do you mean some x/y coordinates or some width/height dimensions? These are supposed to be 2 values, not 1

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in your code.

First you don't really know why you use the `#define` directive. I don't know about the rest of your code, but if you never test the definition of `NOMINMAX` there is no interest to define it. You can look at the WINAPI documentation to know more about the directive (link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-appendix-pre-define-2)).

Then for the window creation, you have to make sure which function you are using, there are 2 functions ([CreateWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) and [CreateWindowW](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww)). The first one uses std::string for class name and title bar and the other one uses std::wstring. You can easily see it with the function suffix 'A' and 'W'. You can look at the WINAPI documentation to know more about strings (link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-170)).

In my case `CreateWindow` refer to `CreateWindowW`.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateWindow  CreateWindowW
#else
```

So your code should be :

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = L"Game Window Class"; 
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback; 

    RegisterClass(&window_class);

    CreateWindowA(window_class.lpszClassName, "Himesh Xakko", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0 );
}
```

Be carefull to use the right function with the right number of parameters, also you should check the WINAPI documentation to understand the parameters and the function.